# Login to mac os user account using apple script from Login window

Tags: macos, applescript, password, login

I have a button on my mac login window which is presented using my daemon application. when I click on that button the login should happen using the user account credentials (user name, password) saved in the daemon application.

can we login to mac user account with username, password using **AppleScript**?

If any user has already logged in, we can switch to any other user using the following code. But if no user is logged in to mac (i.e all the users are logged out) ,can we login to mac with NSAppleScript?

```
set theUser to "test"    --  Mac User name 
set thePassword to "test@123" -- Mac user password
set theUser to do shell script "/usr/bin/id -u " & theUser  
do shell script "/System/Library/CoreServices/'Menu Extras'/user.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -switchToUserID " & theUser  
repeat 2 times      
    delay 2
        try
                tell application "System Events"
                    tell process "SecurityAgent"                    
                        set value of text field 1 of window "Login" to thePassword
                        key code 36             
                    end tell
                end tell            
                exit repeat     
        on error            
            delay 1     
        end try 
end repeat
```

While going through different websites, I understood that CGSession is created only after any user logs in. So the above code doesn't work if all the users are logged out and we are trying to login from the login window of mac.

Please suggest me if I am missing anything while trying to login using **AppleScript** from mac **Login window** when there are multiple users or single user.

Note: I have seen the similar functionality in Splashtop streamer Application.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Are you trying to set up password-less accounts?

Comment: I am nearly certain that AppleScript cannot be run from the login screen (would seem like a potential security hole to allow any scripting where passwords are involved).